# Video Output transparency not working

Tags: animation

I'm trying to animate something and I split it into separate .png image clips, set it to rgba, set alpha to 0, went to film and set it to transparent as well but when I rendered it as a .avi the background is black.

Comment: There is no transparent video. The more close you get is gif animations.

Comment: Adding to @LeoNas comment -  You can render out to a series of png files and later, import those files back into the Video editor (VSE) as a whole, mix that with whatever other videos or images you like.  The alpha layer will work that way.  Archive the series of png images in a zip file for later use.   When importing the image sequence into the VSE, select "image".  Blender will see that it's a sequence and treat it as an alpha layered video.

Comment: I don't think AVI supports alpha channel. Try accessing Quicktime Animation Codec if you really want an embedded alpha.

Answer (score 0):

You can render every shot in a separate .png file, and then, you can upload them to after effects and combine them to an image sequence.